# Spring MVC: Spring Security 4 doesn't intercept

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I try to accomplish authorization through Spring Security for my Spring MVC project (recently updated to `4.2.6.RELEASE`). So I added these dependecies:

```
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-config" rev="4.1.0.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-core" rev="4.1.0.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-crypto" rev="4.1.0.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-taglibs" rev="4.1.0.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-web" rev="4.1.0.RELEASE" />
```

From what I understood I only need to create those classes:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

I would expect that all URL's are blocked now for users who haven't logged in, except "/", "/home", "/login" and "/logout". In reality nothing gets blocked and my webapp is totally accessible. So I gotta be wrong somewhere...

Really appreciate if you could give me a hint here on what my problem might be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your ant matcher and it worked just fine (everything seems fine)  so I think you haven't register your custome security configuration (*SecurityConfig* ) to the spring servlet, it's done with *`@Import`*.

```
@EnableWebMvc 
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "yourpackage" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig .class }) // See here
public class SpringServlet {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/..");
        viewResolver.setSuffix("...");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```